# Goutte - Get all values that exist

Tags: php, goutte

I am using `"fabpot/goutte": "^3.2"` and `PHP 7.3.5`.

I am trying to get data from a website using goutte:

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$subCrawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar.php?month=nov.2019');

$currArray = array();
$impactArray = array();
$reportArray = array();

// currency
$subCrawler->filter('td.calendar__cell.calendar__currency.currency')->each(function ($node) use (&$currArray) {
    $currency = $node->text();
    array_push($currArray, trim($currency));
});

// impact
$subCrawler->filter(' td.calendar__cell.calendar__impact.impact.calendar__impact.calendar__impact > div.calendar__impact-icon.calendar__impact-icon > span')->each(function ($node) use (&$impactArray) {
    $impact = $node->text();
    array_push($impactArray, trim($impact));
});

//report
$subCrawler->filter('td.calendar__cell.calendar__event.event > div > span')->each(function ($node) use (&$reportArray) {
    $report = $node->text();
    array_push($reportArray, trim($report));
});

$multi = array();
foreach ($currArray as $key => $v) {
    $multi[] = [$currArray[$key], $impactArray[$key], $reportArray[$key]];
}
$json_data = json_encode($multi);
file_put_contents('data/data.json', $json_data);
```

As you can see I only get `370` values for my impact array, instead of `376` values, which I cannot add to my final array - `$multi[]` -, as the order is not right.

Find below the different sizes of the array

[image]

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your reply!